# Can you refresh materialised view inside a trigger? Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, triggers

Basically I have a Materialised View which needs to be refreshed once a month when a particular table, HISTORY_TABLE is updated i.e. HISTORY_TABLE is only inserted into c. once a month. The materialised view holds no data related to HISTORY_TABLE so I cannot refresh on commit (to the extent of my knowledge).

From what I have been reading, one cannot refresh a Mview inside a trigger because of the implicit commit when refreshing. Any ideas on how I can go about this?

```
DROP TRIGGER SYSADM.COMPLETE_NOTIF_SMS;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER SYSADM.COMPLETE_NOTIF_SMS
AFTER INSERT
ON SYSADM.HISTORY_TABLE
REFERENCING NEW AS New OLD AS Old
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE

   V_STATUS   NUMBER;
   V_NOTIFICATION_TEXT VARCHAR2(100);
   V_CHECK_CATEGORY VARCHAR2(100);
   
BEGIN
      
      insert into some_table values (v_check_category, v_notification_text,sysdate);  
      -- I want to refresh the Mview/snapshot here 
      DBMS_SNAPSHOT.REFRESH('mview_to_refresh');
                   
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
      
      -- Some variables are set to send an email.  
   
      RAISE;
END NOTIF_SMS;
/
```

Comment: If your MV holds no data related the the History_table update then you should not base the refresh on updating that table. Setup a refresh job (dbms_job or dbms_scheduler) or your external scheduler.  Just because you want them run around the same time does not mean they should be part of the same process.  BTW as currently written if you insert 10K rows into your history table you will refresh your MV 10K times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right; you can't refresh the materialized view directly from the trigger because you can't commit within a trigger. Actually, you *can*, but the trigger then has to be an autonomous transaction but that - unfortunately - won't work because it is then another session so it doesn't see newly added rows into the table on which the trigger fires.

A workaround could be

- a stored procedure (autonomous transaction) as it has to commit
- why? Because it'll schedule a job which refreshes the materialized view, and `dbms_job.submit` requires a commit. As it *propagates* back to the caller (i.e. the trigger) and - remember - you can't commit within a trigger, then procedure has to be an autonomous transaction.
- Job will run a few minutes after the initial insert, presuming that you'll commit the main transaction until then.

Here's an example.

Your `some_table`, the original table contents and a materialized view:

```
SQL> create table some_table (cat varchar2(10), text varchar2(10), datum date);

Table created.

SQL> create materialized view mv_dept as select * from dept;

Materialized view created.

SQL> select * from dept;

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
        30 SALES          CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON

SQL> select * from mv_dept;

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
        30 SALES          CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON

SQL>
```

Procedure (autonomous transaction, schedules a job which refreshes the materialized view):

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_submit as
  2    pragma autonomous_transaction;
  3    i      number;
  4  begin
  5    dbms_job.submit(i,
  6                    'begin DBMS_SNAPSHOT.REFRESH(''mv_dept''); end;',
  7                    sysdate + 1/(24*60),
  8                    'null'
  9                   );
 10    commit;
 11  end;
 12  /

Procedure created.
```

Trigger (which calls the procedure):

```
SQL> create or replace trigger complete_notif_sms
  2    after insert on dept
  3    for each row
  4  declare
  5    v_status            number;
  6    v_notification_text varchar2(100);
  7    v_check_category    varchar2(100);
  8  begin
  9    insert into some_table values (v_check_category, v_notification_text,sysdate);
 10
 11    -- I want to refresh the Mview/snapshot here
 12    p_submit;
 13  end notif_sms;
 14  /

Trigger created.

SQL>
```

Just setting date format; you don't have to do that:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss';

Session altered.
```

Let's try it: insert a row into a table which is source for the materialized view:

```
SQL> insert into dept (deptno, dname, loc) values (1, 'a', 'b');

1 row created.
```

Newly added row is in the table ...

```
SQL> select * from dept;

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
        30 SALES          CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON
         1 a              b
```

... but not in the materialized view because job didn't start yet:

```
SQL> select * from mv_dept;

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
        30 SALES          CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON
```

Job info:

```
SQL> select job, last_date, next_date from user_jobs;

       JOB LAST_DATE           NEXT_DATE
---------- ------------------- -------------------
         8                     12.10.2021 20:34:11

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL>
```

A minute later:

```
SQL> select sysdate from dual;

SYSDATE
-------------------
12.10.2021 20:36:08
```

Job has finished; as it was one-time-only job, it's gone from `user_jobs`:

```
SQL> select job, last_date, next_date from user_jobs;

no rows selected
```

We'd expect a new row in the materialized view as well:

```
SQL> select * from mv_dept;

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
        30 SALES          CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON
         1 a              b

SQL>
```

Right, it's here.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if i got it right, but i refresh my view using global parameters like this :

1. i created a package like this to set the value i want to use :

---

```
create or replace package dwh.DWH_GLOBAL_PARAMS_MANAGER is

  -- Author  : ALI.FIDANLI
  -- Created : 21.03.2019 10:33:25
  -- Purpose : kelepelik


      PROCEDURE SET_ACC_DATE_CTX(PDATE DATE);


end DWH_GLOBAL_PARAMS_MANAGER;    

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY DWH.DWH_GLOBAL_PARAMS_MANAGER IS
      -- Author  : ALI.FIDANLI
      -- Created : 21.03.2019 10:33:25
      -- Purpose : kelepelik
            PROCEDURE SET_ACC_DATE_CTX(PDATE DATE)
          AS
        BEGIN
            dbms_session.set_context('DWH_PARAMS','REPORT_DATE',TO_CHAR(PDATE,'dd.mm.yyyy'));
            dbms_session.set_context('DWH_PARAMS','REPORT_DATE-1',TO_CHAR(PDATE-1,'dd.mm.yyyy'));
          END;
    END DWH_GLOBAL_PARAMS_MANAGER;
```

---

2. I used these parameters inside my view with desired parameters :

---

```
  -- Author  : ALI.FIDANLI
  -- Created : 21.03.2019 10:33:25
  -- Purpose : kelepelik
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW DWH.V_F_ACCOUNT AS
SELECT TO_DATE (SYS_CONTEXT ('DWH_PARAMS', 'REPORT_DATE-1'),'dd.mm.yyyy')  REPORT_DATE,
                 C.ACC_NO,
                 C.ACC_CURRENCY,
 pkg.func(C.ACC_NO, TO_DATE (SYS_CONTEXT ('DWH_PARAMS', 'REPORT_DATE-1'),'dd.mm.yyyy') ,C.ACC_GL_CODE) ACC_GL_CODE,        
            FROM xxxx.tablename C) ACC
```

---

so i set the date using

```
begin
  -- Call the procedure
  dwh.dwh_global_params_manager.set_acc_date_ctx(pdate => :pdate);
end;
```

---

and use my view ....

Let me know if it works for you, if not i will delete my reply